# While an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated

Tags: ios, swift

Boas,
estou a tentar implementar na minha aplicação um loading indicator com uma pequena mensagem, para que o utilizador possa ver que está a ser processada informação(neste caso a ir buscar à API através do Alamofire), porém após usar este metódo:

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "A carregar...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
        let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        AF.request(request).responseDecodable { (response: DataResponse<ModeloDados>) in

            loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            switch response.result{
             case .success(_):
                if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueProcurar", sender: self)
                }
             case .failure(_):
                print("failure")
            }
            print("code: \(response.response?.statusCode)")
        }
```

apenas consigo utilizar uma vez, visto que após passar para a segunda viewcontroller, ao tentar utilizar novamente dá o seguinte erro:

> pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Agradeço desde já qualquer resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema é que você está exibindo um alert quando manda fazer o `pushSegue`. Então, você não consegue fazer a transição, pois existe um alerta na tela enquanto você tenta fazer a segunda transição. Recoomendo que você faça um dismiss no seu alert, antes de tentar exibir outro `UIViewController`

Comment: Penso que já estou a fazer dismiss com o
            "alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)"

Answer (score 0):

O `dismiss` é executado de forma assincrona, ou seja, o `dismiss` não terminou de executar quando o `performSegue` é chamado

Para isso é possível utilizar o `completion:`, segue o exemplo abaixo de como seu código ficaria

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "A carregar...", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

AF.request(request).responseDecodable { (response: DataResponse<ModeloDados>) in

    loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        switch response.result{
          case .success(_):
            if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueProcurar", sender: self)
            }
          case .failure(_):
            print("failure")
        }
        print("code: \(response.response?.statusCode)")
    })
}
```